# SignatureDoesNotMatch Error in AWS V4 Signed Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, pre-signed-url

I have generated the presigned url for get request using the same algoritthm mentioned in the documentation of AWS.
This is working.
But when I Post/Put the data the signature mismatch error is present.

Below is a sample curl :-

curl --location --request POST 'https://<bucket_name>.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testFolder/testing1.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=<access_key_id>%2F20211006%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211006T113405Z&X-Amz-Expires=3000&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost%3Bx-amz-content-sha256%3Bx-amz-date&X-Amz-Signature=' 
--header 'x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD' 
--header 'x-amz-date: 20211006T113405Z' 
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain'